# Eigenvalues of unitary matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, unitary-matrices

I have a sparse unitary matrix with complex entries and want to compute all its eigenvalues. Unfortunately, matlab doesn't like this. If I try do enter eigs(A, N) (A the matrix, N its size), it tells me that I should use eig(full(A)) instead. This is awfully slow ... comparred to the computation for self-adjoint sparse matrices.

Is there any way to do this quicker?

Comment: You said "sparse", but is there any particular pattern in the sparsity?

Comment: It's a CMV matrix. See Section 4.2. of Barry's OPUC book available at http://www.math.caltech.edu/opuc/sampleopuc.html ... (set |alpha_N| = 1 to get an N times N matrix).

Answer (score 2):

An unitary matrix $A$ is normal, i.e. $A^HA=AA^H$. Let's define $\operatorname{Re}(A):=(A+A^H)/2$ and $\operatorname{Im}(A):=(A-A^H)/(2i)$. Note that $\operatorname{Re}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ are self adjoint (sparse) matrices, and satisfy $\operatorname{Re}(A)\operatorname{Im}(A)=\operatorname{Im}(A)\operatorname{Re}(A)$, i.e. they commute.

So you can compute the real and imaginary parts of the eigenvalues separately. To match corresponding real and imaginary parts together, you have to look at the mutual eigenspaces.

Comment: 'you have to look at the mutual eigenspaces' Perhaps it's more simple (and efficient) to compute just the real part and, knowing that $|\lambda|=1$, try out the two possible imaginary parts.

Comment: @leonbloy Maybe it can be done simpler for unitary matrices, like you describe. I'm not really how to "try out" the imaginary parts, especially when $\operatorname{Re}(A)$ has duplicate eigenvalues.
I also tried to explain why matlab and most libraries for computing eigenvalues don't provide special routines for normal matrices.

Comment: This is possible  ... but: 1. If one would start from an upper Hessenberg matrix, one would get a full matrix, and whereas the computation is fast for upper Hessenberg matrices, it's awfully slow for full ones.    2. This seems somewhat complicated to write. My current code to computing with the full matrix is like 20 lines, this would be somewhat longer ...

Comment: If $A$ has $m$-nonzero entries, $A+A^H$ will have at most $2m$-nonzero entries. So if the computation is fast for upper Hessenberg matrices, I guess it's because these matrices are quite sparse Hessenberg matrices, and this sparsity will be preserved as far as possible. I don't fully understand your comment with the 20 lines. Just write a subroutine to compute the eigendecomposition of normal/unitary $A$. Writing eigs((A+A')/2,N) is probably not the difficult part, so I guess your complaint is about the matching part, which I haven't described in detail. Is this missing detail the real issue?